# Is there way to split single natTable virtually as two table

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I have eclipse Nat Table of 40 columns . Right now, It showed as single table with horizontal scroll bar. I have been try to show 20 columns as first part, and remaining columns in second part.. it will looks like virtually two nat Table in the UI

I have tried to split the Grid layout and nat Table layout with row layout with packing as true.

```
GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
natTable.setLayoutData(gridData);
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Answer (score 1):

The NatTable composite as such does not support layouts. So the code you are showing does not work. Dependent on your requirement you either need to use the freeze feature or the split viewport feature.

Dependent on what you are writing (which is not much) I suspect that you need the freeze feature where, you or even a user, can dynamically freeze/fix the first 20 columns so they are fixed and not scrollable, and then the rest of the table will be scrollable. You can see this in our examples app in this example: [FreezeExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_513_FreezeExample.java)

If the first 20 columns should also be scrollable, you need to implement a split viewport, which is slightly more complicated. For this you can have a look at the following example: [HorizontalSplitViewportGridExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_504_Viewport/_5044_HorizontalSplitViewportGridExample.java)

Comment: Right now, I have two NatTable , ( 20 columns each ) and fits exactly to my widgets when it is maximized, and horizontal scroll appear when widgets is resized.  Now, I want to make it into single table with layout like two tables 20 columns each. Reason being merge into single table is that I have to have group by function, column dragging facilities. Having two many listener between two table is quite annoying.,  "HorizontalSplitViewportGridExample" is somewhat filling half to my desire, but I want to have view port up and down, not side by side. I hope it clears. Thanks in advance

Comment: Then have a look at the VerticalSplitViewportGridExample